# Zooming into an element without changing the element's size

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, flot, zooming

For example; if I had a flot canvas graph and I wanted to be able to view a closeup of one of the areas, I want to be able to zoom into a specific area and have a scrollbar appear for horizontal and vertical panning so every section can be viewed. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything is possible, but flot doesn't support that by itself.  Your best bet would be to use the panning and zooming functions built into flot (via the navigate plugin), but then for the scrollbars, you might have to overlay some fake scrollbars (perhaps using a div with `overflow:scroll`, as @Wolfy87 suggested) and hook them up to the flot graph.

Flot triggers `plotpan` and `plotzoom` events when the graph has moved, so you would use them to keep your scrollbars in sync.

I haven't seen anyone do this before, so I can't point you towards an example.  But the code doesn't seem unreasonable to put together.

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea flot had a navigation.js

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the `zoom` CSS property. Here is [a little example](http://jsfiddle.net/Wolfy87/ADeYq/) of it in action.

As for the scroll bars, you could try placing the zoomed element within a parent which has `overflow: scroll;` set.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think firefox supports this. [22:58:36.634] Unknown property 'transition'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://fiddle.jshell.net/Wolfy87/ADeYq/show/:21

Comment: In fact it does, with -moz-transform: scale(2.0) - however this makes the actual div bigger.

Comment: True, it only works in modern browsers, but if it needs to work with a canvas I would imagine that you are already targeting modern browsers. @Consciousness is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Wolfy87/ADeYq/1/) more like what you need?

Comment: Not really, that doesn't work unless I changed it to -moz-transform: scale(2.0) then when it's zoomed the text disappears.

Comment: This is a fairly good answer, however I decided to go with the built in flot zoom feature which I did not know about xD